# Check if an excel cell exists on another worksheet in a column - and return the contents of a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-match

What I want to do is to say if the contents of cell `D3` (on current worksheet) exist in column `A` in the first worksheet (in my case entitled list). (and they always do exist somewhere). Return the contents of the corresponding row in Column `C`.

In other words if the matching cell is found in Row `12` - return data from `C12`.

I've used the following syntax but I can't seem to get the last part to work correctly.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D3,List!A:A, 0)), "No Match", VLOOKUP(D3,List!A:A,1,TRUE))
```

How to fix the formula?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use following formulas.

For Excel 2007 or later:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,List!A:C,3,FALSE),"No Match")
```

For Excel 2003:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D3,List!A:A, 0)), "No Match", VLOOKUP(D3,List!A:C,3,FALSE))
```

Note, that

- I'm using `List!A:C` in `VLOOKUP` and returns value from column № `3`
- I'm using 4th argument for `VLOOKUP` equals to `FALSE`, in that case `VLOOKUP` will only find an exact match, and the values in the first column of `List!A:C` do *not* need to be sorted (opposite to case when you're using `TRUE`).

Comment: It worked! 

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,List!A:C,3,FALSE),"No Match")

I'm not entirely sure i understand the List!A:C (the A:C) part. I thought the function worked as such - find the data in one column and return the contents of another (What if i only want it to search in Column A and always return Column C or D ... but never search in those columns).

Comment: `List!A:C,3,` means that yor're going to search in first column of range `List!A:C` (i.e. `List!A:A`) and return corresponding value from third column of range `List!A:C` (i.e. `List!C:C`)

Comment: Years later, still a fantastic solution. Thanks!